# Validating an email string in .net using EmailAddressAttribute, but not on an attribute

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations

I want to be able to do this:

```
string email = "some@email.com";
bool isValid = IsValidEmail(email);
//returns true
```

...but use the logic Microsoft has already given us in **EmailAddressAttribute**.

There are hundreds of good and bad implementations of IsValidEmail out there, and I don't want to add my own, when I can use something, Microsoft has already thought about. It stands to reason, that they will do a better job than me.

In recent ASP.Net versions, we have System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, which provides us with the excellent [EmailAddressAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs), that lets us decorate our models like this:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The [class is sealed](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs), so I cannot call EmailAddressAttribute.IsValid()

Is there a good way I can utilize what Microsoft has already done? Is there a method somewhere in the .Net framework, that let's me test strings against data-annotations, that I have overlooked?

Something along the lines of..:

```
var emailChecker = new DataAnnotationsChecker<EmailAddressAttribute>();
string email = "some@email.com";
bool isValid = emailChecker.IsValid(email);
//returns true
```

If you cannot imagine why I would want this, think about getting a List and want to check which ones are valid emails.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use the `EmailAddressAttribute` to do the validation.

The `sealed` means that you cannot create another class that inherits from it. Doesn't mean you cannot use it.

Created some unit tests and works fine

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_Use_Email_Address_Attribute_To_Validate_Email() {
    var emailChecker = new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute();
    string email = "some@email.com";
    bool isValid = emailChecker.IsValid(email);
    Assert.IsTrue(isValid);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Should_Use_Email_Address_Attribute_To_Invalidate_Email() {
    var emailChecker = new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute();
    string email = "some@emai l.com";
    bool isValid = emailChecker.IsValid(email);
    Assert.IsFalse(isValid);
}
```

Comment: I would have sworn, I already tried that... But of course this does in fact work. I feel silly now. Thanks. :)

Comment: A serious question here: Why is this not the approved/accepted method of checking email addresses in .Net? Microsoft is going to do email validation better than any one of us will.

Comment: @ShaiCohen doesn't mean they can't make mistakes as well like the rest of us. We're all coders. It does save you from having to write one yourself. Here are two completely different implementations of the same attribute [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs), [mvc](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Web.Mvc/EmailAddressAttribute.cs)

Comment: I'll add something I discovered relative to what is "valid". With the sample email address "mark@gmailcom" - Checking validity with System.Net.Mail.MailAddress returns true because technically it is. EmailAddressAttribute IsValid returns false because the dot is missing. For my purposes the address is not valid without the dot in the domain part.

Answer (score 4):

`EmailAddressAttribute` **IS NOT SAFE** !!!

They claim that .NET is safe and secure! But if you don't read the source code, you will be misled and make mistakes!

#### The following code, are you serious???

https://source.dot.net/#System.ComponentModel.Annotations/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs,c3ae85dfd8a9f58c

```cs
public override bool IsValid(object? value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(value is string valueAsString))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // only return true if there is only 1 '@' character
    // and it is neither the first nor the last character
    int index = valueAsString.IndexOf('@');

    return index > 0 &&
           index != valueAsString.Length - 1 &&
           index == valueAsString.LastIndexOf('@');
}
```

See how the people at Microsoft responded. They just leave the safety issues alone and claim to have designed such a trap for us to step on!

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/65968

Comment: You might want to have a look at how complex an email address actually is. The intention of the attribute is to reject anything that is not a potential email address. It does not validate that the email actually exists (annotations cannot do that). Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrGfahzt-4Q

Comment: No one is asking for the validation to verify the email exists, but it misses very basic checks that would rule out bad addresses, such as checking that it cannot end in a period.

Answer (score 2):

**Use MailAddress**
This is a useful technique for reading and validating an email address, even from '*Elmer Fudd <e.fudd@example.com>*' styled inputs (such as those copy-pasted from email clients).

```
private string? ExtractEmailAddress(string raw)
{
    try
    {
        var address = new MailAddress(raw);
        return address.Address;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also use `[EmailAddress]` attribute to indicate the required type to API documentation.

Comment: They've added a `TryCreate()` static method that returns TRUE if the address is _valid in its form_ (i.e. RFC-compliant), so you don't have to use `TRY...CATCH` anymore. Also, the version given here would be more correctly implemented by only catching `FormatException`, rather than all/any possible exceptions.
Here's an example of doing validation using TryCreate instead: `private bool IsValidEmailForm( string raw ) => raw is not null && MailAddress.TryCreate( raw, out _ );`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've been using lately to validate the form of an email string:

```
/// <summary>Validates the <i>FORM</i> of an email address in a supplied string using both
/// <see cref="System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.TryCreate"/> and 
/// <see cref="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute.IsValid"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <returns><b>TRUE</b> if the passed value is a valid <i>FORM</i> of email address.</returns>
/// <remarks><b>NOTE</b>: This function doesn't determine if the supplied address is an 
/// <i>actual</i>, functional, email address, it only reports whether or not it conforms 
/// to the defined standards for the format of one.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="value">The string whose contents are to be tested.</param>
/// <param name="acceptEmpty">If <b>TRUE</b> (the default), the parser will pass an empty 
/// address. If you don't want that, set this to <b>FALSE</b>.</param>
// Notes: By default, if the 'value' is genuinely null, OR is all whitespace, this will 
// return FALSE; but if it's just EMPTY, or is valid, it will return TRUE. We can't use
// the 'string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()' function because being empty is considered to be a
// valid state, while being all-whitespace (or null) is not.
public static bool ValidateAddr( string value, bool acceptEmpty = true ) =>
    (value is not null) && !Regex.IsMatch( value, @"^[\s]+$" ) &&
    ( acceptEmpty || (value.Length > 0) ) &&
    (new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute()).IsValid( value ) &&
    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress.TryCreate(value, out _ );
```